# Creating a Dictionary from txt

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I have a couple of lines inside a text that i am looking to turn the first word to a key (space is between each) with a function, and the rest to follow as values.
This is what the text contains:

```
FFFB10 11290 Charlie
1A9345 37659 Delta
221002 93323 Omega
```

The idea is to turn the first word into a key, but also arrange it (row underneath a row) visualy, so the first word(FFFB10) is the key, and the rest are values, meaning:

```
Entered: FFFB10
Location: 11290
Name: Charlie
```

I tried with this as a beginning:

```
def code(codeenter, file):
  for line in file.splitlines():
    if name in line:
        parts = line.split(' ')
```

But i dont know how to continue (i erased most of the code), any suggestions?

Comment: How do you want your values to be organized: list, tuple, set? There must be exactly one value for one key; if you have more than one, they have to be collected in some compound data type. It is not clear what you mean by "arrange it visually."

Comment: What pops up in my head instantly is that you should create an empty dictionary before the `for` loop, and then append each key-value pair into the dictionary as the file gets parsed. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: DYZ: when i say "visually" i mean clean, after the function works, to print the key in the first row, underneath the value, underneath it the second value and so on.

Comment: Hey Jerrybibo, i havent tried, i am new to this language, can you describe a bit more please?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you managed to extract a list of lines without the newline character at the end.

```
def MakeDict(lines):
    return {key: (location, name) for key, location, name in (line.split() for line in lines)}
```

This is an ordinary *dictionary comprehension* with a *generator expression*. The former is all the stuff in brackets and the latter is inside the last pair of brackets. `line.split` splits a line with whitespace being the delimiter.

---

Example run:

```
>>> data = '''FFFB10 11290 Charlie
... 1A9345 37659 Delta
... 221002 93323 Omega'''
>>> lines = data.split('\n')
>>> lines
['FFFB10 11290 Charlie', '1A9345 37659 Delta', '221002 93323 Omega']
>>> def MakeDict(lines):
...   return {key: (location, name) for key, location, name in (line.split() for line in lines)}
...   
>>> 
>>> MakeDict(lines)
{'FFFB10': ('11290', 'Charlie'), '1A9345': ('37659', 'Delta'), '221002': ('93323', 'Omega')}
```

---

How to format the output:

```
for key, values in MakeDict(lines).items():
    print("Key: {}\nLocation: {}\nName: {}".format(key, *values))
```

Comment: Hey.
Thanks for your response, but those lines are inside a text, and they are written like i wrote in my question.
I also want that the key will look like this:
Name: FFFB10
Location: 11290
Code: Charlie
Every row in under another, how can i do it?

Comment: @Tom, it doesn't really matter where they come from. Just make sure you can obtain a list of lines, so that this code would work.

Answer (score 0):

See ForceBru's answer on how to construct the dictionary. Here's the printing part:

```
for k, (v1, v2) in your_dict.items():
    print("Entered: {}\nLocation: {}\nName: {}\n".format(k, v1, v2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')]

final_dict = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in f}
```

Assuming the data is structured like this:

```
FFFB10 11290 Charlie
1A9345 37659 Delta
221002 93323 Omega
```

Your output will be:

```
{'FFFB10': ['11290', 'Charlie'], '221002': ['93323', 'Omega'], '1A9345': ['37659', 'Delta']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields).

```
from collections import namedtuple

code = {}
Code = namedtuple('Code', 'Entered Location Name')
filename = '/Users/ca_mini/Downloads/junk.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        row = row.split()
        code[row[0]] = Code(*row)
>>> code
{'1A9345': Code(Entered='1A9345', Location='37659', Name='Delta'),
 '221002': Code(Entered='221002', Location='93323', Name='Omega'),
 'FFFB10': Code(Entered='FFFB10', Location='11290', Name='Charlie')}
```